# Slider Revolution plugin cannot be activated due to a PHP error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, php-7, revolution-slider

I have Slider Revolution 5.2.6 and WP 4.8. The stacktrace looks like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\framework\base-admin.class.php:71 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-content\plugins\revslider\admin\revslider-admin.class.php(572): RevSliderBaseAdmin::addMetaBox('Revolution Slid...', '', Array, NULL)
>       #1 C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-content\plugins\revslider\admin\revslider-admin.class.php(73): RevSliderAdmin->addSliderMetaBox() #2 C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-content\plugins\revslider\admin\revslider-admin.class.php(44): RevSliderAdmin->init() #3 C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-content\plugins\revslider\revslider.php(168): RevSliderAdmin->__construct('C:\Users\Roma\D...') #4 C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php(1882): include('C:\Users\Roma\D...') #5 C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-admin\plugins.php(164): plugin_sandbox_scrape('revslider/revsl in C:\Users\Roma\Desktop\Dropbox\LOCAL\upwork\wp-content\plugins\revslider\includes\framework\base-admin.class.php on line 71

Answer (score 17):

This happens if you're running PHP 7+. There are 3 possible solutions:

- If you can, try updating the plugin to the latest version - they should fix it sooner or later.
- Go to *plugins\revslider\includes\framework\base-admin.class.php*, line 21, and change
  `private static $arrMetaBoxes = '';` to `private static $arrMetaBoxes = array();`
- just switch back to PHP 5.x (I wouldn't recommend it, but it can be the easiest thing to do).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend going into the class and updating `base-admin.class.php`, that change will just be removed if there are any updates. You need to check if there is a PHP 7 version of this plugin where the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @giollianosulit why not? If there's an update, hopefully it will resolve the issue, so the change won't be needed any more. And if someone got the plugin pre-packaged in their theme (like I did), they won't be getting any updates unless they activate it.

Comment: It's more so in general, if you edit a core file of a library and forget about it later on, an update **might potentially break things**. Your users would get a blank page if it does break. I would just look for a PHP7 version slider you know is working. It will save you trouble later on. Or if SliderRevolution has a repository, creates pull request that has your fix for it.

Comment: @giollianosulit _In general_ you may be right, but in this particular case - if you're not planning to activate the plugin and get any updates - I think it's the best solution. At least that's what I did, and I'm happy with it.

Comment: I agree with @zarsky. I needed to get this plugin to activate before I could update it and this is the first thing that worked for me in 2 days! (I would mark this as the answer) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In my case the second one option work perfectly.